# Get file's name within a file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract some texture string path from a .flt file. But I'm unable to get a clean selection on the line of text I want. How should the script be written?

```
$file="E:\PwShell\test.flt"
$s=Get-Content $file -Encoding Ascii
$s.Split("?")|Select-String -Pattern 'jpg'
```

I am unable to only select the lines with the jpg. I am unable to use the 'jpg$' in the current script. I also not abler to use wildcard.

Below is what was returned-

```
 E:\PwShell\Folder-A\20170219_154.jpg                                                   

                                           @ 
 E:\PwShell\Folder-A\subFolder\20170219_154811.jpg                                      

                                          C    F @
```

Comment: You should share a few lines of the source data as well, please.

Comment: Sorry, which source data are you asking? I had included the script that I was using and the returned value I got from the script.

Comment: Source data here would be the `.flt` file

Comment: It looks that the `test.flt` file in question isn't a _text_ file but a **_binary_** one?